# TypeScript Error when Indexing Object with String Variable

Tags: typescript, express

I'm working on a project where I'm dynamically creating routes and handling them in an Elysia(~Express) application. I'm encountering an issue with TypeScript's type checking system when trying to index an object using a string variable. It just leaves if I make the `app:any` but then there is no point right.

```js
//server.tsx
function createRoutes(path: string) {
    const routes = readdirSync(path);

    routes.forEach(async (route) => {
        const dirPath = `${path}/${route}`;
        const isDir = statSync(dirPath).isDirectory();

        if (isDir) {
            createRoutes(dirPath);
            const routePath = dirPath.split(`src/pages/`)[1];
            const filePath = `./src/pages/${routePath}`;

            let fileName: string = readdirSync(dirPath)
                .filter((file) => statSync(`${dirPath}/${file}`).isFile())
                .map((file) => basename(file).split(".")[0])[0];

            if (fileName == `page`) {
                const componentName =
                    route.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + route.slice(1);
                const componentPath = `${filePath}/page`;

                app.get(routePath, async ({ headers, html }: any) => {
                    const { [componentName]: Component } = await import(
                        componentPath
                    );
                    return html(sendPage(headers, Component));
                });
            } else if (fileName == `route`) {
                const apiPath = `${filePath}/route`;

                const route = await import(apiPath);
                for (const fun in route) {
                    app[fun](routePath, () => route[fun]());//<= error
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```js
///route.tsx
let message = `hi mom`;

export async function get() {
    return message;
}
export async function post() {
    return message;
}
export async function patch() {
    return message;
}
```

```js
//error
[{
    "resource": "/d:/Projects/Web Dev/Learning/fireBEH/server.tsx",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "7053",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Elysia<\"\", { request: {}; store: {}; schema: {}; error: {}; meta: { defs: {}; exposed: {}; schema: { \"/\": { get: { body: unknown; headers: undefined; query: undefined; params: undefined; response: { '200': Promise<any>; }; }; }; }; }; }>'.\n  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Elysia<\"\", { request: {}; store: {}; schema: {}; error: {}; meta: { defs: {}; exposed: {}; schema: { \"/\": { get: { body: unknown; headers: undefined; query: undefined; params: undefined; response: { '200': Promise<any>; }; }; }; }; }; }>'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 73,
    "startColumn": 21,
    "endLineNumber": 73,
    "endColumn": 29
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the types?  `npm i @types/express` or `yarn add @types/express`
This is what you generally need to do (for other frameworks/libraries than express)